# Cannot get the attribute value in Internet Explorer when using onkeyup in Lightening Component Salesforce

Tags: javascript, html, salesforce-lightning

I have the following code which works perfectly fine in Chrome and every other browser i have tested so far:

```
 <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
    <div class="slds-col slds-size--1-of-1 slds-small-size--3-of-4 slds-medium-size--2-of-3 " onkeyup="{!c.enterClicked}">
      <div class="inputWrapper searchInpFastlane" >
        <c:input aura:id="PortalFastlaneSearchBar" value="{!v.searchInput}" type="text" placeholder="{!v.placeholderText}" useIcons="false" class="noMargins heightXL searchInpFastlane3" labelClass="hidden"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-col slds-size--1-of-1 slds-small-size--1-of-4 slds-medium-size--1-of-3 searchBtnPad">
      <div class="buttonWrapper searchBtn">
        <c:button buttonLabel="Search" onclick="{!c.searchButtonClicked}" buttonClass="valmetPrimaryButton" showImage="false"/>
      </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

and my controller looks like this:

```
    enterClicked : function(component, event, helper)
{
       console.log("1");
    if(event.keyCode && event.keyCode === 13)
    {
           console.log("2");
        try
        {
            console.log("3");
            console.log(component.get("v.searchInput"));
            helper.search(component, helper);
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            console.log("4");
            Console.log(e);
        }
    }
},

searchButtonClicked : function(component, event, helper)
{
    try
        {
            console.log(component.get("v.searchInput"));
            helper.search(component, helper);
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            Console.log(e);
        }
}
```

I just dont know why `console.log(component.get("v.searchInput"));` does not seem to display anything instead it displays **undefined** when clicking enter.

It works when searchButtonClicked is called by clicking a button

Answer (score 0):

managed to solve it by adding this line of code within try statement `document.getElementById('searchKeyword').blur(); , basically aura attributes seems not to update , bind unless u have loose the focus from the input, so what I am doing I am programatically loosing focus from the input and that just works!

My code became like:

```
enterClicked : function(component, event, helper)
{
    if(event.keyCode && event.keyCode === 13)
    {
        try
        {
             var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
             var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

            if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))  // If Internet Explorer, return version number
            {
                document.getElementById('searchKeyword').blur();
                helper.search(component, helper);
            }
            else  // If another browser, return 0
            {
                helper.search(component, helper);
            }
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            Console.log(e);
        }
    }
},
```